# Positioning values of stacked barchart in the center using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I've created a stacked barchart and faceted using two variables. I'm unable to position the values in the barchart in the middle, it either appears at the extremes or overlaps. The expected image is the following:

[image: link to the image]

I've pasted the script below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)

library(reshape2)

library(ggplot2)


year<-c("2000","2000","2010","2010","2000","2000","2010","2010")

area<-c("Rural","Rural","Rural","Rural","Urban","Urban","Urban","Urban")

sex<-c("Male","Female","Male","Female","Male","Female","Male","Female")

city<-c(58,61,74,65,51,55,81,54)`

village<-c(29,30,20,18,42,40,14,29)

town<-c(13,9,6,17,7,5,5,17)

data<-cbind.data.frame(year,area,sex,city,village,town)

dre<-melt(data,id.vars = c("year","area","sex"))

dre <- arrange(dre,year,area,sex,variable) %>% 
    mutate(pos = cumsum(value) - (0.5 * value))


a <- ggplot(dre,aes(factor(sex),value,fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity',position="stack")

b <- a + 
    facet_wrap(factor(year)~area)

c <- b + 
geom_text(aes(label=paste0(value,"%"),y=pos),
        position="stack",size=2,hjust=0.85,color="black")

d <- c + 
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_fill_brewer()

print(d)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You no longer need to calculate the position variable. Starting in ggplot2_2.2.0, text can be stacked and centered via `position_stack`.

The relevant line of `geom_text` code is below.  Notice I don't need to use the "pos" variable at all for text placement.

```
geom_text(aes(label=paste0(value,"%")),
              position = position_stack(vjust = .5), size = 2, color = "black")
```

The code for the plot and the resulting graph:

```
ggplot(dre, aes(factor(sex), value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(factor(year)~area) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value,"%")),
              position = position_stack(vjust = .5), size = 2, color = "black") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image]